# c++ boost library cannot open file

Tags: c++, xml, boost

I tried to work with the boost library to read/write configuration files but I just don't get it.

I even can't run the example code from boost.org (5 Minute Tutorial)
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/property_tree/examples/debug_settings.cpp

I've downloaded the boost_1_49_0.zip package and unzipped it to my c++ program folder. The code compiles (TheIDE - U++) but it always says "Error: debug_settings.xml: cannot open file" which basically means that the program works, but runs into the exception.

I didn't change the code, I just copy and pasted it to get a working example which I could try to understand then. But I don't even get this one to work. (Since it's exactly the same as in the link, I don't paste the code here... unless you think it's better.)

Please help me... or point to a different way to store variables in a file with some kind of structure (I wan't to learn a way that works for windows and linux, because some of my apps are cross-platform.)

Thanks.

EDIT: debug_settings.xml is in the same folder as the .cpp file

EDIT2: Working now, the debug_settings.xml is now in the folder where the executable is stored. (in my case, U++/TheIDE it's C:\upp\out\MyApps\MINGW.Debug.Debug_Full.Sse2 for debugging)

Comment: Is there a debug_settings.xml file around?

Comment: yes there is, in the same folder as the .cpp file

Comment: FWIW, in the future, any time you have some kind of "file not found" error like this, the first thing you should try is to use the file's absolute path. If the code works with the absolute path, the file is in the wrong folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The configuration file would need to be in the working directory of the executable when it's running.

Comment: Sometimes it's the small things... Thank you so much, it's working now!